# Display the label data into nextview label

Tags: iphone, xcode, label

I have a problem, I was hoping the community could help me with.
I Kept two class and Label

1.ItemdetailViewcontroller, `IBOutlet UILabel*countLbl`;

2.CountItemViewController, `IBOutlet UILabel currentNumber`;

Here,i Kept `countLbl` in (First Class).I need to display the value of my (second-class)`currentNumbe`r value to the `countLbl` which have been changing the counter value.(ie)that incrementing and decrementing value by pressing the navigation button from 2nd view to 1st view.

Comment: plz..never post do the needful or any sentence that make us appear as your worker in future.. :D

Comment: also edit your post to make it better formatted..and explain with an example what you need..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the value of the label in the second class in nsuserdefault

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
[prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"integerKey"];  
[prefs synchronize];
```

And in your firstclass you can get the value stored in default and display it in label

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];
```

Hope this helps.....